# Get the innerhtml of element which is loading at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is div which loads elements at rum time.

```
<div class="name" id="projct_name"></div>
```

after loading elements its becomes:-

```
<div id="projct_name" class="name">
  <div>
     <span >Proof testers</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the value of span.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prodct_name=$('#projct_name').find('div').find('span').html();
  alert(prodct_name);
});
```

Each time page load get the alert null value because elements loads after alert.
I want to delay my js code so that all elements of page loads before my code run. It can be possible??

Comment: try `var prodct_name=$('#projct_name').text();` you have a space in your opening `span` tag, might be causing some error..

Comment: its working fine in static condition. Text is used for text boxes not for span or div. My problem is div load the elements after javascript alert.

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zvcxutx8/)**. Note you can do it directly like I mentioned in fiddle. No need to go level by level for its children unless there is some exceptional case.

Comment: You can use `text` for `span` and `div` too.. Here is the **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/zvcxutx8/2/)** Are you loading the contents/elements through some `ajax`?

Comment: how you are loading elements in #projct_name div ?

Comment: Div loads the emements run time when complete page load by some external javascript code. My problem is div load the elements after javascript alert thats y showing null value.

Comment: so the dynamic content (elements) is loaded on `document.ready` ??

Comment: I dont know because using external js file. I want to delay my js code so that all elements of page loads before my code run.
It can be possible??

Comment: include the above JS code in you external JS file, after loading elements dynamically...

Comment: Sorry Not Working. 
The <div class="name" id="projct_name"></div> loads the elements after few second after alert.

Comment: can you show how you loading the elements (JS code) ??

Comment: its sigma.js loading products from json file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:-

```
  function pageLoadCompelet(){
    var prodct_name=$('#projct_name').find('div').find('span').html();
    alert(prodct_name);
  }
```

And call this function on window.onload :-

```
  window.onload=pageLoadCompelet;
```

Comment: i already tried this.. sorry not working.Problem is div loads the elements after few second of alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Jquery Initialize](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize) will solve your issue.

**Step 1:** Insert this in the head-section of your page:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize/master/jquery.initialize.js"></script>
```

**Step 2:** Place the following javascript below or above the other code you already tried:

```
$("#projct_name span").initialize( function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

The plugin uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which is a really robust way of handling DOM changes.

Comment: i dont khow how to use.

Comment: I added some more details on how to use it.